# What is the message of the movie Spring Breakers?

Tags: spring-breakers

Taking into account the ending of [Spring Breakers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2101441/), what is the larger message that the viewer is supposed to take away from the movie? Is there one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From interviews with writer/director Harmony Korine about *Spring Breaker*s, it appears ambiguity and reaction were the goals rather than the delivery of a message:

> "I make films so there is a reaction and the reactions are extreme,"
>   says Korine, sucking on a strawberry in the London office of the
>   film's PR agency. "But this one is just amped up to ten."  [GQ](http://www.gq-magazine.co.uk/entertainment/articles/2013-04/05/harmony-korine-interview-spring-breakers-film)
>
> But that's why you make films; to provoke some kind of discourse. Or
>   you hope that it has something that is emotionally confusing to
>   people. I purposefully try to make films in that grey area, where
>   things are morally ambiguous. It's like life: good people do horrible
>   things and bad people do good things, and there's beauty in horror and
>   horror in beauty. Very rarely are things so clearly defined.  [GQ](http://www.gq-magazine.co.uk/entertainment/articles/2013-04/05/harmony-korine-interview-spring-breakers-film)
>
> ... it was never meant to be a kind of documentary or an exposé on
>   something. And it is more like a reinterpretation of those things.
>   It’s something that’s more like a pop poem, or almost like the real
>   world but pushed into something more kind of — I don’t know —
>   hyper-poetic. And […] it works on its own logic. So I would say […]
>   it’s connected to the culture, and maybe there’s a zeitgeist in some
>   way. But it’s also something separate. [Daily Free Press](http://dailyfreepress.com/2013/04/07/interview-spring-breakers-harmony-korine-and-ashley-benson/)
>
> Yeah, I mean … it was never meant to be a documentary or an essay. It
>   was meant to be kind of a pop poem, or an impressionistic
>   reinterpretation. It was more of this idea of something that was more
>   experiential, like a ride or a video game that was more manic and
>   physical. So once we got into the edit room — as I started to develop
>   it — the movie had this really liquid narrative and this energy. This
>   film that was closer to a sort of drug trip, more hallucinatory, with
>   a kind of peak, a transcendence, you just disappear for a little while
>   … and then you’re back. So once I started to figure that out, it kind
>   of led itself. But I was never interested in being ironic or making
>   these characters seem like a joke. [Stereogum](http://www.stereogum.com/1298072/harmony-korine-on-skrillex-gucci-mane-spring-breakers-and-why-florida-is-like-a-whole-other-country/interview/)
>
> I liked spring break. I like it as a backdrop for the beginning of the
>   film. I liked that it was kind of over the top … and that people would
>   see it as a completely base and vile rite of passage for young people.
>   But while I was collecting imagery and photographs of that time, there
>   was all this hyper-violent and hyper-sexualized imagery with all these
>   innocent, childlike details … like in the nail polish, in the book
>   bags, the bikinis, in the beer bongs, on the Mountain Dew bottles. I
>   started to like that there was this kind of coded inner vernacular. I
>   kind of thought of spring break as a metaphor for what happens in the
>   rest of the film. What I most wanted to explore was Alien’s world —
>   the trap houses, that kind of beach noir, the violence, the
>   dilapidated rotting yachts in the backyards of these houses in
>   Florida. [Stereogum](http://www.stereogum.com/1298072/harmony-korine-on-skrillex-gucci-mane-spring-breakers-and-why-florida-is-like-a-whole-other-country/interview/)
>
> People get pissed at the film and stuff, and it’s like why does
>   everybody need it to deliver a message about really obvious things …
>   don’t you know that killing is bad? Why do you need me to tell you
>   what to think all the time? Why can’t you just dream on it? Why are
>   people so scared of going to places where they’re forced to reconcile
>   what they know or come up with their own feelings or forge their own
>   connections? People get pissed when it’s not all one way, when
>   someone’s not all bad or all good. But that is not interesting to me.
>   It’s too easy to judge people and condemn people.[Stereogum](http://www.stereogum.com/1298072/harmony-korine-on-skrillex-gucci-mane-spring-breakers-and-why-florida-is-like-a-whole-other-country/interview/)